# Making 3D Contour Plots

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, contour

I have been trying to get the "example" picture (generated with a 3D graphic calc) using Python for a few days now, but keep running into troubles getting the segments of the plot other than the peak in the middle to show up to scale.

I am using this code:

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
X, Y = np.mgrid[-1:1:30j, -1:1:30j]
Z = (2*X*Y) + (1/np.sqrt(X**2+Y**2))
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap="autumn_r", lw=0.5, rstride=1, cstride=1)
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 10, lw=3, cmap="autumn_r", linestyles="solid", offset=-1)
ax.contour(X, Y, Z, 10, lw=3, colors="k", linestyles="solid")
plt.show()
```

Which produces this graph.

[image: Here is where I currently am.]

It is close, but it should look more like this one. When I lower the 30j in attempts to bring it down and hope the flares on the sides are more pronounced, it gets rid of the entire peak. I am trying to get to this.

[image: This is where I hope to be.]

Comment: The flares are beyond the range you are plotting.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try the following line?

```
X, Y = np.mgrid[-7:7:100j, -7:7:100j]
```

Comment: I still do not get the desired result. It just shows the "wings" but no peak.

Comment: Use ax.set_zlim3d(-3, 6) and you should see a similar picture